# enum completely set to 0

Tags: c++, g++, qnx

I have 2 enums in a header file.

```
enum first {
alpha,
delta,
gamma,
};

enum second {
sigma = 20,
zulu,
omega,
};
```

I have no issues with compilation. However, at runtime all of second enum is set to 0. i.e sigma, zulu and omega are all 0's. The first one however is proper from 0 to 3.

Whats is going on?
It works on my Linux PC but my QNX is having issues.

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: C or C++? which compiler version? Unable to reproduce, http://ideone.com/ASZmwn

Comment: c++ on QNX. I dont know what compiler qnx uses. I am trying to start second at 20. I forgot to add that .

Comment: What do you mean "it's all 0"? That makes no sense.

Comment: Starting at 20, it still behaves as expected: http://ideone.com/AeiBXd. Please provide an example that shows the problem.

Comment: I mean sigma, zulu and omega are evaluated to 0.

Comment: @preetam, but how do you check that they are?

Comment: Those enums are tags and I dump them to a file along with time stamps.

Comment: Crazy idea: show that code. You're still asking us to debug a problem *we can't possibly see*.

Comment: @preetam: Your description of the problem does not seem to make any sense at all. Moreover, the behavior you describe is "magical" to say the list. It is highly unlikely that what you say happens actually happens. You are probably misinterpreting something. Which is why we need to see what exactly made you believe that they are zeros.

Comment: It seems to be a random compilation issue. I just did a make clean and make all. Issue is gone.  Dint change the code at all.

Comment: @preetam welcome to QNX, you are going to run into plenty of crazy problems ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.

```
#include <iostream>

enum first { alpha, delta, gamma, };
enum second { sigma, zulu, omega, };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using namespace std;
  cout<<alpha<< endl;
  cout<<delta<< endl;
  cout<<gamma<< endl;
  cout<<sigma<< endl;
  cout<<zulu<< endl;
  cout<<omega<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

as expected.

Comment: OP uses `sigma = 20` (even if it should work too).